# listplot plotstyle=xvalues with vertical offset

Tags: pst-plot

I am using

```
\listplot[plotstyle=xvalues,labelsep=2pt,fontscale=6,xunit=0.0101,decimals=0]{\easter}
```

and want the `xvalues` offset vertically a little bit. How can I get that?